# SetInputMask In Acumatica

Tags: c#, dynamic, erp, acumatica, input-mask

I need a masking settings that can be dynamic. and I found **SetInputMask** In *development guide*, but I do not find a way to use it, whether here there who have been using these **SetInputMask**? how the example to use it?

Thank

Answer (score 3):

```
    protected virtual void _(Events.RowSelected<FilterDAC> e)
    {
        if (e.Row != null)
        {
            FilterDAC row = e.Row as FilterDAC;
            PXDBStringAttribute.SetInputMask<FilterDAC.stringField>(e.Cache, e.Row, ">CCCC");
/*PXStringAttribute for non DB backed fields*/
        }
    }
```

If you are trying to change masking on a text box the control must be declared as a PXMaskEdit as shown below :

```
<px:PXMaskEdit runat="server" DataField="StringField" ID="edStringField" CommitChanges="True" AlreadyLocalized="False"></px:PXMaskEdit>
```

Answer (score 1):

May be this will be helpful.  Thanks

```
public class APInvoiceEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension<APInvoiceEntry>
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        PXDBStringAttribute.SetInputMask<APInvoice.docDesc>(Base.Document.Cache, ">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC");
    }            
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it can be set from extension constructor? I looked at existing app usage and it's typically in _FieldSelecting handlers.